# JMeter,JDBC Request,Stored Procedure,Oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle11g

i need to call this PL\SQL function structured like this:

```
FUNCTION FunctionName ( p_lang_IN            IN  SESSIONS.s_lang%TYPE,
                       p_user_IN            IN  VARCHAR2,
                       p_pwd_IN             IN  VARCHAR2,
                       p_source_IN          IN  SESSION_SOURCE.ss_userid%TYPE,
                       p_sessionstring_OUT  OUT SESSIONS.s_id%TYPE,
                       p_pwd_type           IN  NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                       P_PSWD_STATUS        OUT NUMBER            
                      )
RETURN  NUMBER;
```

I'm using a JDBC Request created like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBTlH.jpg)

I get the following error:

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'FunctionName' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I suppose an error in the syntax of the call ... but that is?
Thanks in advance
Bye

Comment: I don't know how "JDBC Request" works, but - a function is supposed to return one value. Your returns a NUMBER, while there are also two OUT parameters. I'd rather switch to a **procedure** with 3 OUT parameters. That's what the first error (PLS-00221) suggests; you're calling it as if it were a procedure.

Comment: Add more details of your jdbc request please. And when define functions in PL/SQL, it is always started as “ create or replace function...”